# How to delete a image from Device (Local DB) in IOS Cordova using Objective-C

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova

I am working on **iOS - Cordova** Cross platform .

I am getting image path from Javascript side using below code -

```
 NSString *fileName =[command argumentAtIndex:0];
```

and i want to delete image from this image path Using Objective-c.

What should i do ?  Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it like this:

```
NSString *fileName = [command argumentAtIndex:0];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", fileName]];
[fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:NULL];
```

Comment: Thanks,   and
if I want to convert Base64 to Path than what should i do ?
please help

@gvuksic

Comment: @kishor http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/encode-decode-using-base64.html

Comment: I am getting Base64 from [command argumentAtIndex:0];
So how to convert it into path ? 
 
I tried but its not working.

Please help

Comment: you are getting base64 data? NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] 
  initWithData:[command argumentAtIndex:0] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: @kishor NSString *fileName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:[command argumentAtIndex:0] options:0] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Hi , this Code is Not Working Means I am Not Able to delete Image Please help.

Comment: Fetching argument at index Zero is Giving Path.

Answer (score 0):

```
 -(void)deleteImageFromDevice:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
 {
   @try
   {
       //File Name Getting from JS side
       NSString *fileName = [command argumentAtIndex:0];

      //Make a component Sepratation of File Name
      NSArray *items = [fileName componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];

      //Get File(Image) At last index
      NSString* FileAtLastIndex =[items objectAtIndex:([items count]-1)];

      //creating file manager
      NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

      //Create a Local Path
      NSString *documentPath =[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
                              (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)
                              objectAtIndex:0];

     //Appending the IconImages Folder In Local Path
     NSString *filePath = [documentPath
                          stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"IconImages"];

      //Appending The File(Image), we get it from array Last index
      NSString *filePathAtLastIndex =
                [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:FileAtLastIndex];

      NSError *error=nil;

      //Checking that File is removed or Not.
      BOOL success =
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePathAtLastIndex error:&error];

      //If file is Removed
        if (!success)
        {
          NSLog(@"Could not delete file -:%@ ",[error localizedDescription]);
        }
     }
  @catch(NSException *exception)
  {
      NSLog(@"DeleteImageFromDevice exception %@",exception);
  }
 }
```